# access order details when admin creates new order woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

This hook can be used to access order_details after checkout.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($this,'save_order_data'), 10);

public function save_order_data( $order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    echo "<pre>Order id is".$order_id."</pre>";
}
```

But how could i access the same when order is created in back-end (admin side)? I couldn't find any hook ? Or is there any common hook that can be accessed even if order is placed from back-end or front end

Comment: What do you want to do with the order details via the admin created order?

Comment: It's a broad answer. But A hook executes after payment complete is, `woocommerce_payment_complete`. You can use it to achieve this task.

Comment: i want to access the order details such as product name, quantity etc

Comment: As @Bhavin has stated your question is too broad.  Give us a better explanation as to what you aim to achieve then we can help.

Comment: I just want $order_id so as to get order details. I want to check order status @AndrewSchultz

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can you ??